# MVVM - Binding and Update approach

Tags: wpf, mvvm

i code a programm in WPF using the MVVM structure.
Now i have a Datagrid bound to an Observable Collection of Article.
The Article were loaded from a ArticleRepository connected to a SQL-Server.
The user can change them directly in the Grid, or open a detail-View of an Article.

My question is:
What is the best way to update the data in the SQL-Server ?
Should i update every edited article (row) in the Grid, or are the other better strategys ?

Thanks for your help so far.

Bye jogi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that subscribing to the row edit ending event for the datagrid allows for small, manageable updates to the database.  We run everything over WCF services and sometimes our clients have slow internet connections, so tiny updates make for happy clients.  We also bind the selected item in the datagrid to an object on the view model and then have a detail form that the user can double click to get more details than the datagrid provides.  This makes sure that both the datagrid and details form are bound to the same changes.  I would stick to individual changes to the database until you hear there is too much network traffic, or chatter (if that ever occurs).  It's easier to scale up to large commits than it is to scale back down.